# Image processing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript/jQuery to manage a slide show that can handle random occurrences of portrait or landscape images. 
The code works fine if there is an "alert" in the first function called to process a loaded image. 
It fails without the alert. 
I am testing locally and the images are loaded into an array when the page loads. 
The files are quite small. I suspect however that the issue is one of timing.

Below is the function where the Alert works. I don´t exactly understand what the code is doing as I am new to jQuery. It would help to know what the function is doing and a suggestion of how to fix the issue. I can post a working sample if it would help.

```
function FixImages(fLetterBox) {
    $("div.aspectcorrect").each(function (index, div) {
    var img = $(div).find("img").get(0);
    alert("FixI")
    FixImage(fLetterBox, div, img);
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you might be passing in the wrong arguments for the `.each()` callback. If you want `div` to refer to the element that is currently being looked at in each iteration, using `$(this)` should work:

```
function FixImages(fLetterBox) {
    $("div.aspectcorrect").each(function (index) {
        var img = $(this).find("img").get(0);
        FixImage(fLetterBox, div, img);
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry..doesn´t work!
I have been messing about with some code that is supposed to trigger function call when image has loaded without much success.
The bizarre thing is that the routine runs fine for a seemingly random number of images and then refuses to convert any more.

The code etc is rather messy at the moment. I will make a clean version and let you have a look.